# PCI Ethernet card causes IRQ "nobody cared" in syslog

Tags: 11.10, networking

I have installed a new PCI Gigabit Ethernet card, yet it is not working well. It works for a few minutes then suddenly stops running. I found logs in `/var/log/syslog` saying `irq 18: nobody cared (try booting with the "irqpoll" option)` and tried the option. Now it takes several hours before the network interface goes down. Running `ifdown eth0 && ifup eth0` makes it up again, but it does not look like a permanent solution.

Below is information that I think seems relevant to this issue:

### /var/log/syslog

```
Jan  6 06:21:51 ubuntu kernel: [  436.677602] irq 18: nobody cared (try booting with the "irqpoll" option)
Jan  6 06:21:51 ubuntu kernel: [  436.677662] Pid: 0, comm: swapper Tainted: G         C  3.0.0-14-generic-pae #23-Ubuntu
Jan  6 06:21:51 ubuntu kernel: [  436.677665] Call Trace:
Jan  6 06:21:51 ubuntu kernel: [  436.677672]  [<c1542c41>] ? printk+0x2d/0x2f
Jan  6 06:21:51 ubuntu kernel: [  436.677680]  [<c10b3e59>] __report_bad_irq+0x29/0xd0
Jan  6 06:21:51 ubuntu kernel: [  436.677691]  [<f844c5ae>] ? rtl8169_interrupt+0xbe/0x210 [r8169]
Jan  6 06:21:51 ubuntu kernel: [  436.677696]  [<c10b4224>] note_interrupt+0x104/0x150
Jan  6 06:21:51 ubuntu kernel: [  436.677701]  [<c10b274e>] handle_irq_event_percpu+0x9e/0x200
Jan  6 06:21:51 ubuntu kernel: [  436.677706]  [<c1026ae0>] ? msi_set_affinity+0x60/0x70
Jan  6 06:21:51 ubuntu kernel: [  436.677710]  [<c12bef7f>] ? msi_set_mask_bit+0x6f/0x80
Jan  6 06:21:51 ubuntu kernel: [  436.677714]  [<c10b28eb>] handle_irq_event+0x3b/0x60
Jan  6 06:21:51 ubuntu kernel: [  436.677719]  [<c10b4960>] ? unmask_irq+0x30/0x30
Jan  6 06:21:51 ubuntu kernel: [  436.677723]  [<c10b49ae>] handle_fasteoi_irq+0x4e/0xc0
Jan  6 06:21:51 ubuntu kernel: [  436.677725]  <IRQ>  [<c155e352>] ? do_IRQ+0x42/0xc0
Jan  6 06:21:51 ubuntu kernel: [  436.677734]  [<c1057360>] ? irq_exit+0x60/0xa0
Jan  6 06:21:51 ubuntu kernel: [  436.677737]  [<c155e429>] ? smp_apic_timer_interrupt+0x59/0x88
Jan  6 06:21:51 ubuntu kernel: [  436.677741]  [<c155e1b0>] ? common_interrupt+0x30/0x38
Jan  6 06:21:51 ubuntu kernel: [  436.677747]  [<c105007b>] ? default_handler+0x2b/0x70
Jan  6 06:21:51 ubuntu kernel: [  436.677752]  [<c12e25e7>] ? intel_idle+0xb7/0x110
Jan  6 06:21:51 ubuntu kernel: [  436.677758]  [<c14397dd>] ? cpuidle_idle_call+0x7d/0x240
Jan  6 06:21:51 ubuntu kernel: [  436.677762]  [<c1008c7a>] ? cpu_idle+0x8a/0xc0
Jan  6 06:21:51 ubuntu kernel: [  436.677767]  [<c1527355>] ? rest_init+0x5d/0x68
Jan  6 06:21:51 ubuntu kernel: [  436.677773]  [<c17fa774>] ? start_kernel+0x352/0x358
Jan  6 06:21:51 ubuntu kernel: [  436.677777]  [<c17fa3b3>] ? pass_bootoption.constprop.2+0xe2/0xe2
Jan  6 06:21:51 ubuntu kernel: [  436.677782]  [<c17fa0ba>] ? i386_start_kernel+0xa9/0xaf
Jan  6 06:21:51 ubuntu kernel: [  436.677784] handlers:
Jan  6 06:21:51 ubuntu kernel: [  436.677808] [<f844c4f0>] rtl8169_interrupt
Jan  6 06:21:51 ubuntu kernel: [  436.677846] Disabling IRQ #18
Jan  6 06:25:53 ubuntu kernel: [  678.228016] ------------[ cut here ]------------
Jan  6 06:25:53 ubuntu kernel: [  678.228027] WARNING: at /build/buildd/linux-3.0.0/net/sched/sch_generic.c:255 dev_watchdog+0x1e6/0x1f0()
Jan  6 06:25:53 ubuntu kernel: [  678.228031] Hardware name: MS-7680
Jan  6 06:25:53 ubuntu kernel: [  678.228033] NETDEV WATCHDOG: eth0 (r8169): transmit queue 0 timed out
Jan  6 06:25:53 ubuntu kernel: [  678.228035] Modules linked in: snd_hda_codec_hdmi snd_hda_codec_realtek snd_hda_intel snd_hda_codec snd_hwdep snd_pcm snd_timer snd i915 drm_kms_helper drm i2c_algo_bit mei(C) video coretemp soundcore snd_page_alloc shpchp psmouse serio_raw rt3070sta lp parport usb_storage uas r8169 ahci libahci
Jan  6 06:25:53 ubuntu kernel: [  678.228065] Pid: 0, comm: swapper Tainted: G         C  3.0.0-14-generic-pae #23-Ubuntu
Jan  6 06:25:53 ubuntu kernel: [  678.228068] Call Trace:
Jan  6 06:25:53 ubuntu kernel: [  678.228075]  [<c1050462>] warn_slowpath_common+0x72/0xa0
Jan  6 06:25:53 ubuntu kernel: [  678.228080]  [<c147a286>] ? dev_watchdog+0x1e6/0x1f0
Jan  6 06:25:53 ubuntu kernel: [  678.228083]  [<c147a286>] ? dev_watchdog+0x1e6/0x1f0
Jan  6 06:25:53 ubuntu kernel: [  678.228088]  [<c1050533>] warn_slowpath_fmt+0x33/0x40
Jan  6 06:25:53 ubuntu kernel: [  678.228092]  [<c147a286>] dev_watchdog+0x1e6/0x1f0
Jan  6 06:25:53 ubuntu kernel: [  678.228098]  [<c105d8af>] call_timer_fn+0x2f/0x110
Jan  6 06:25:53 ubuntu kernel: [  678.228102]  [<c147a0a0>] ? qdisc_reset+0x40/0x40
Jan  6 06:25:53 ubuntu kernel: [  678.228106]  [<c105efab>] run_timer_softirq+0xeb/0x210
Jan  6 06:25:53 ubuntu kernel: [  678.228109]  [<c147a0a0>] ? qdisc_reset+0x40/0x40
Jan  6 06:25:53 ubuntu kernel: [  678.228114]  [<c1056fb0>] ? local_bh_enable_ip+0x90/0x90
Jan  6 06:25:53 ubuntu kernel: [  678.228118]  [<c1057031>] __do_softirq+0x81/0x1a0
Jan  6 06:25:53 ubuntu kernel: [  678.228122]  [<c1056fb0>] ? local_bh_enable_ip+0x90/0x90
Jan  6 06:25:53 ubuntu kernel: [  678.228125]  <IRQ>  [<c1057376>] ? irq_exit+0x76/0xa0
Jan  6 06:25:53 ubuntu kernel: [  678.228132]  [<c155e429>] ? smp_apic_timer_interrupt+0x59/0x88
Jan  6 06:25:53 ubuntu kernel: [  678.228137]  [<c1557299>] ? apic_timer_interrupt+0x31/0x38
Jan  6 06:25:53 ubuntu kernel: [  678.228141]  [<c105007b>] ? default_handler+0x2b/0x70
Jan  6 06:25:53 ubuntu kernel: [  678.228147]  [<c12e25e7>] ? intel_idle+0xb7/0x110
Jan  6 06:25:53 ubuntu kernel: [  678.228153]  [<c14397dd>] ? cpuidle_idle_call+0x7d/0x240
Jan  6 06:25:53 ubuntu kernel: [  678.228157]  [<c1008c7a>] ? cpu_idle+0x8a/0xc0
Jan  6 06:25:53 ubuntu kernel: [  678.228163]  [<c1527355>] ? rest_init+0x5d/0x68
Jan  6 06:25:53 ubuntu kernel: [  678.228169]  [<c17fa774>] ? start_kernel+0x352/0x358
Jan  6 06:25:53 ubuntu kernel: [  678.228173]  [<c17fa3b3>] ? pass_bootoption.constprop.2+0xe2/0xe2
Jan  6 06:25:53 ubuntu kernel: [  678.228177]  [<c17fa0ba>] ? i386_start_kernel+0xa9/0xaf
Jan  6 06:25:53 ubuntu kernel: [  678.228180] ---[ end trace 582a116d2bf2b697 ]---
Jan  6 06:25:53 ubuntu kernel: [  678.244049] r8169 0000:03:00.0: eth0: link up
```

### System

- CPU: Intel Celeron G530
- Motherboard: MSI H61M-E23 (B3)
- RAM: Samsung DDR3-1333 2x4GB
- HDD: WD Caviar Blue WD10EALX 1TB
- TP-Link TG-3269 PCI Gigabit Ethernet card
- OS: Ubuntu 11.10

The onboard LAN (eth1) is working without any problem.

Comment: OP are you still looking for an answer? If so, you may need to repost your question as this is flagged for closure. Regards,

Comment: It seems you triggered a bug. So I would suggest writing a bug report. see http://askubuntu.com/q/5121/236 for hints.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems you hit a bug here. Please see [Bug 38632 - IRQ Nobody Cared on Sandybridge Additional Ethernet Card](https://bugzilla.kernel.org/show_bug.cgi?id=38632). This seems the same kind of bug you encountered.

Askubuntu can not do anything useful for you in this case. I advise to follow the bug report, maybe add some more information and wait until it is fixed.